# Unknown response from WINSCARD.DLL method SCardTransmit on O2Micro reader with response length information

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, pcsc, winscard

For communcation with a Smartcard I use the WINSCARD.DLL as an API to send APDU commands to Smartcards. For a couple of cardreaders this is working as expected, but somehow I get an unkown return (it is not on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms936965.aspx) value from the method `SCardTransmit` if I send the command to a O2Micro reader.

What is working:
If I send command (values in hex):

```
CLA: 00, INS: A4, P1: 02, P2: 04, Lc: 02, Data: "4401", Le: (not present)
```

I get the response `SW1: 61. SW2: 1F`

The response tells that there are `0x1F` bytes available. So I send command:

```
CLA: 00, INS: A4, P1: 02, P2: 04, Lc: 02, Data: "4401", Le: 1F
```

But on that command I get no data and return value `0x57`.

My question is if anyone knows what the return value `0x57` is telling and maybe a way how to solve or workaround it.

Comment: Fix your spelling in subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error code is one of the windows [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from winerror.h: `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. This almost always means that your APDUs are ok, but the `SCardTransmit` arguments are the problem. I recommend looking closely at the `pbRecvBuffer` parameter. Caveat: I've only used SCard functions with C++, not with C#.

PC/SC functions can return standard windows error codes as well as PC/SC-specific error codes. Note the bit about the `FormatMessage` call: you can use that to make error reporting a little more generic with predefined error messages supplied by windows.

Comment: I call the function as:
`SCardTransmit((uint)Card, IntPtr.Zero , SendBuffer, (uint)SendBuffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero, RecvBuffer, ref RecvLength)`
RecvBuffer is a byte array of 257 bytes and RecvLength is 0. I also tested with RecvLength is 257. But still it give me the same error.

Comment: With some effort I found that an invalid prefered protocol was given to the `SCardConnect` method. The parameter `dwPrefProtocol` (the forth in the list) was put as 1|2. Typically it uses 2 in development systems, but 1 on production systems. I changed it hard coding using value 2 and after that it started working. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you try with 255 bytes max? I believe that's the maximum amount of bytes for that part...